# Index, match function doesn't recognize texted format cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have `TextBox` which contain number over 15 digits. When I copy the textbox value into excel cell, starting from digit 15th excel will change it zero number. This is Excel's way if cell format as number. I change the cell format from number to text, and input manually the number, and its work.

But when I use `Index`, `Match` function on macros, it doesn't work and I get

> Run-time error 1004 "Unable to get match property of the
>   WorksheetFunction class

This is the code I use for index, match function

```
Dim b As Double

b = TxtCvNo.Text

With Application.WorksheetFunction    
    If .CountIf(Sheet2.Range("G:G"), b) = 1 Then    
        TxtCVId.Text = .Index(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), .Match((b), Sheet2.Range("G:G"), 0))     
    Else
```

`b` is the `TextBox` value.

`Match` function doesn't recognize `b` as this value were input as 'text' in Excel cell

How can I copy the textbox value into cell as text to avoid digit 15th, 16th and so on change to zero. How can I fix the index, match function after it.

this screen shot of my Data. I use `Index` and `Match` to identify whether the coupon 1,2,3 has been use as coupon ref, and then tell me the ID Respondent use that Coupon.
[screen shot data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umysW.png)

Comment: have you read my answer and code below ? any feedback ?

Comment: yes, It work now. But I didn't use     res as you have in your code. Thanks alot.

Comment: Then please mark as "ANSWER" by clicking on the check-mark next to my answer, it will turn green

Comment: why the match function sometime is work but sometime is not?

Comment: it depends how the values you are looking for formatted, in your case with very long numbers stored as text, it can get tricky. You can edit your post and add a screen shot of the data you are trying toMatch with

Comment: have you seen my data? what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub IndexMatchConv()

Dim b As String
Dim Res As Variant

' for my test format and set a value with 21 digits as Text in cell "G2"
Sheet2.Range("G2").NumberFormat = "@" ' format as Text
Sheet2.Range("G2").Value = "123456789112233445566"
b = Sheet2.Range("G2").Value
MsgBox Len(b) ' <-- result 21

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Res = .CountIf(Sheet2.Range("G:G"), b)
    If .CountIf(Sheet2.Range("G:G"), b) = 1 Then
        Res = .Match((b), Sheet2.Range("G:G"), 0) < --Res = 2
        'TxtCVId.Text = .Index(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), .Match((b), Sheet2.Range("G:G"), 0))
    Else
        ' do something
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this solution could answer my problem, but sometimes I still get error for `match` function.

Comment: I found the problem actually with `countif` function, which only read 15 characters. When I use that function to find the data on collum H, `countif` find it on column G, thats where the `match` function become error. Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: @Hepk1211 let's do this, open a new post, put your screen-shot of your data, add you modified code, and describe what is the issue - this will allow other users (besides me) to assist you.